# loading Ajax response data into knockout array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, knockout.js

I am trying to load the response data of a AJAX request into a knockout observable array.

This is my AJAX request:

```
self.loadAssets = function(projectId) { 
    $.ajax({
      url: "/Assets/getJson/"+projectId,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(json_data){
        console.log(json_data);
        alert('success');
        $.each(json_data['getassets'], function(){

            viewModel.addAsset(this.type, this.content, 'user-'+this.type, this.width, this.height, this.top, this.left);
        });
      }
    });

};
```

In the inspector, I can see that the request to "/Assets/getJson/id" was successful (200 code)
but the alert is never called??

I have spent the whole day looking at examples and tutorials but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

My Json file looks like this:

```
{ 
"getassets":[ 
    { 
        "id":1, 
        "type":"Text", 
        "content":"[Your Text]", 
        "width":"200", 
        "height":"100", 
        "top":"0", 
        "left":"0", 
        "selected":true 
    }, 
    { 
        "id":2, 
        "type":"Text", 
        "content":"[Your Text]", 
        "width":"200", 
        "height":"100", 
        "top":"100", 
        "left":"200", 
        "selected":true 
    }, 
    { 
        "id":3, 
        "type":"Text", 
        "content":"[Your Text]", 
        "width":"200", 
        "height":"100", 
        "top":"0", 
        "left":"0", 
        "selected":true 
    }, 
]
}
```

Comment: Try to add the error handler, may be you receive incorrect json.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this happen several times where the content type didn't match up.

Check if the content type of the output is set to application/json

Also add to your ajax call

```
contentType: "application/json"
```